# MVC Image - Dispaly in a Tab instead of downloading to a file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, png, filestream

I have the following controller method which gets a PNG from a web api.

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> RealTimeUpdate(string fundName)
        {
        string docPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RealTimeUpdate"].Replace("{fundname}",fundName).ToString();
        docPath = docPath.Replace("\\\\", "\\");
        docPath = docPath.Replace("\"", "");

        string url = ServiceUrl + "api/RealTime/" + fundName;
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var dataStream = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            if (dataStream == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            var _buffer = JsonConvert.DeserializeAnonymousType(dataStream, new { _buffer = (byte[])null })._buffer;

            // If user decides to save the file, this will help...
            //Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + Path.GetFileName(path));
            return File(_buffer, "application/png");
        }
        return View("Error");
    }
```

I call it like this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("RealTimeUpdate", "Documents", new { FundName = "RealTimeUpdate"})" class="btn rt-info rtBtn" target="_blank">Real Time Update</a>
```

As you can see, I have target="_blank", however, instead of displaying the image in a new tab, it downloads it to my documents folder. How can I get it to display in a tab?

Comment: this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/16142574/5586581

Comment: Yes, it could. Thanks.

Comment: nice, i set my answer in answer box for contribute community

Comment: You have no control over this since its a browser setting. But another option is to use `FileStreamResult` - see Shyju's answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13219704/how-to-show-a-pdf-file-in-the-browser-tab-from-an-action-method)

Answer (score 0):

You need a ImageController to render that.

once you have a controller you can render as follows:

```
public class ImageController{

public ActionResult ShowImage(string path) 
{

    return File(path);
}

}
```

in your views:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("Render","Image", new {id =1  // or path })" />
```

this answer was taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/16142574/5586581

Comment: The has nothing at all to do with the question! (OP is already return a `FileResult`)

Comment: If you read a post the main difference is the form that show the image, I show that when return a image it can show so <img src=“@Url.Action(“Render”, “ShowImage”)/>

Comment: And how do you think that would show in another tab!

Comment: It depending from tools were utilice for tabs for example Jquery tabs  so https://jsfiddle.net/31oftamq/221/

Comment: OP is referring to a browser tab :)